# Should we avoid using the Params of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

AsyncTask has a very curios method `task.execute(Params... params)`

For example, downloading a url:

1. `new DownloadTask(context).execute(url);`
2. `new DownloadTask(context, url).execute();`

How should we choice, the Param or the constructor?

Comment: Yes avoid param at all cost

Answer (score 0):

As the asker, I think the constructor is better.

**The Reason**:

1. remove the generics PARAM, there is only two genericses left.
2. the constructor has name suggest in IDE.
   consider you should place a url. `new Task(String url)` vs `execute(String... params)`
3. no ambiguous for reusing. Many newer of android will write:

   ```
   DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
   task.execute(url);
   task.execute(url2);
   ```

   But this is wrong.
   [AsyncTask Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

   > The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)
4. detecting the error in compile time.

   ```
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       String url = params[0];
       return download(url);
   }
   ```

   Someone missing the param `new Task().exec();` will get a NPE at runtime.

I think we should avoid using the param.